# How to create a Standalone Executable program in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, executable

I want to create a program that could work on any computer without the source code, How is that possible? and does it make any difference if I used OpenGL in the Program?

Comment: You mean any versions of Windows/MacOs/Linux and all processor architectures?

Comment: "Any computer", taken literally, isn't going to happen. There are some incompatible architectures. Even common systems require different builds, but C++ always makes a file that can run without the source on any *compatible* computer.

Comment: I don't want the program to work on different platforms, I just want it to work on different computers with the same platform.

Comment: So you want to compile an executable and then run that executable in other computers with the same OS and architecture (platform)? I'm undestanding it wrong or isn't that the way all exectutables work? :)

Answer (score 8):

You **cannot code a program in C++ that would work on *any* computer** without giving your source code to be compiled.

For example, you could perhaps code in C++ a program, and compile it and build an executable which works on Windows x86-64, but that executable won't work on Linux (or MacOSX), and it won't work on ARM (e.g. Android phones) unless you consider using [emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing your code with Visual C++ you may need to consider two options:

1. Make sure you link all libraries statically.
2. Install on the target computers along with your program Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package corresponding to the Visual C++ version you use like the one at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555. Some installer generating software will make it for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would link your object file with some sort of a platform dependent loader. This loader loads your object and does all the stuff to start it from memory. Normally you can tell your compiler to link your object file and compile a blob. OpenGL is a powerful API and is usually distributed as a.dynamic linked library and is linked at runtime to your program. If I remember you just have to make sure the dll is where you want it and load the dll in your program from start.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ program is compiled and linked into an executable before it is run. You should be able to find that executable in a `Debug` or `Release` subfolder of the folder containing your project.

OpenGL, if you're not using GLUT or similar libraries, should just come with Windows and pose no additional problems. If you do use GLUT, it's enough to bundle the .dll file with your application.

In any case, the source code won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a program that could work on any computer without the source code, How is that possible? and does it make any difference if I used OpenGL in the Program?

By compiling and linking it into an executable. As long as you're not using some interpreted language (like Python, Ruby or such) you're presented with an executable inevitably. The biggest problem you may/will run into is dependencies on libraries. However those are linked into a binary as well. So what you're going to ship will be just a .exe; and some .dll maybe. Usually you'd wrap this in a installer package for deployment to the end user. Installers are created with something like the "NullSoft Installer System" (NSIS).

OpenGL itself is just a API, provided by a system library. So you don't ship OpenGL with your program, but expect the user to have it installed on the system (which will be the case if he installed the graphics drivers).